# mysql AND operator not working for passing multiple parameter

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

```
try {
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbtable', $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$data = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ' . $conn->quote($name).' AND id = '. $conn->quote($id));
$data->execute();

while($row = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "ID : ".$row['id'].'</br>';
    echo "Name : ".$row['name'].'</br>';
    echo "Name : ".$row['header'].'</br>';
}
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

The above works for one parameter (name) but when i use AND operator it shows no results. URL is as given below.

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/page.php?id=2&name=xyz
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have records with requested `name` and `id` fields in table?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250434/pdo-quote-method!

Comment: @Hasi, it's good that you're using `PDO::prepare`, but you're not using it correctly. Parameters must be set separately, that's the whole point of prepared statements. See examples: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Yes.I tried by using with any one of one vaiable (name or id) at a time, it works well.

Comment: Perhaps you never have `name` and `id` in one row, or with the figures you try?

Comment: I tried simple MySQL code(without using PDO) still i couldn't get the results for multiple parameters :(

Answer (score 2):

As [mentioned in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php), you're strongly advised to use parametrized queries, like so:

```
$data = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = :name AND id = :id');
$data->bindParam(":name", $name);
$data->bindParam(":id", $id);
```

If this still does not work, I would suggest running a similar query directly against your database, through either phpMyAdmin or the [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), to verify that the query actually returns anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = '$name' AND id <> '$id' ");
```

The above code worked for me.